# Android Studio Issue- Build Failed with an Exception

Tags: android, ios, android-studio, flutter

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > Multiple task action failures occurred:
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.2-6040484-windows Daemon #12: Compile 'C:\Users\Abh\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-th\values-th.xml' timed out, attempting to stop daemon.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
  >   A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   AAPT2 aapt2-3.6.2-6040484-windows Daemon #9: Compile 'C:\Users\Abh\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApplication\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-en-rAU\values-en-rAU.xml' timed out, attempting to stop daemon.
  >       This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.

This is the issue, I keep getting whenever I try to run flutter.
Could anyone provide a solution to this...please?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the whole picture it is really hard to say, though, according to official documentation [About AAPT](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/aapt2) issue seems to be related to your resource bundle. Check if you are using everything correct links to your resources. I believe issue have occurred in your `.xml` files `values-th` and `values-en-rAU`. It is a good idea if there are some strings marked as `translatable` check if there are corresponding values in those file